# How to use a while loop on a C++ list?

Tags: c++, algorithm, while-loop, merge, mergesort

I am using a merge sort on C++ list. So far, I could divide the list into half with the assign function.

Since lists don't use indexes like an array or vector, I have trouble with translating this while loop for my lists.

```
i = 0; j = 0; k = l;

//marge temp arrays to real array
while (i < nl && j < nr) {
    if (larr[i] <= rarr[j]) {
        array[k] = larr[i];
        i++;
    } 
    else {
        array[k] = rarr[j];
        j++;
    }

    k++;
}

while (i < nl) {       //extra element in left array
    array[k] = larr[i];
    i++; 
    k++;
}

while (j < nr) {     //extra element in right array
    array[k] = rarr[j];
    j++; 
    k++;
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Use iterators and `std::advance` instead of  indices and `++`.  Actually you can use `++` for std::list, but if you find yourself needing to jump around the list, use `std::advance`.

Comment: We will need to know the type of list your are using to help you. for std::list you can use ranged based for loops.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a while loop for lists then instead of indices to access elements of lists you should use iterators.

Nevertheless there is already the standard algorithm `std::merge` declared in the header `<algorithm>` in the C++ standard library.

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> list1 = { 1, 3, 5 };
    std::list<int> list2 = { 0, 2, 4 };
    
    std::list<int> list3;
    
    std::merge( std::begin( list1 ), std::end( list1 ),
                std::begin( list2 ), std::end( list2 ),
                std::back_inserter( list3 ) );
                
    for ( const auto &item : list3 )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

The standard algorithm does not change the merged lists. It creates a new list based on the elements of the merged lists.

Or you can write such a function yourself as for example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>

template <typename T>
std::list<T> merge_lists( std::list<T> &list1, std::list<T> &list2 )
{
    std::list<T> list3;
    
    typename std::list<T>::iterator first1 = std::begin( list1 ),
                                    first2 = std::begin( list2 );
    typename std::list<T>::iterator last1  = std::end( list1 ),
                                    last2  = std::end( list2 );

    while ( first1 != last1 && first2 != last2 )                                    
    {
        if ( *first2 < *first1 )
        {
            list3.push_back( *first2 );
            first2 = list2.erase( first2 );
        }
        else
        {
            list3.push_back( *first1 );
            first1 = list1.erase( first1 );
        }
    }
    
    list3.insert( std::end( list3 ), first1, last1 );
    list1.erase( first1, last1 );
    
    list3.insert( std::end( list3 ), first2, last2 );
    list2.erase( first2, last2 );
    
    return list3;
}

int main()
{
    std::list<int> list1 = { 1, 3, 5 };
    std::list<int> list2 = { 0, 2, 4 };
    
    std::list<int> list3 = merge_lists( list1, list2 );
    

    for ( const auto &item : list3 )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Again the program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

This implementation of the function in fact moves elements from the merged lists to the result list. That is the merged lists after calling the function will be empty. It seems such a function is more appropriate for your task of sorting a list.